# concat lists together element for element

Tags: python

I have two lists `device_list` and `new_setpoint_list` that I am trying to concat together. What I want for a final output is this:

```
['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14/ZN-SP/75.00000762939453',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13/ZN-SP/74.9999771118164',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15/ZN-SP/75.0',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11/ZN-SP/74.0',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9/ZN-SP/75.99999237060547',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/7/ZN-SP/75.0',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21/ZN-SP/74.0',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/16/ZN-SP/75.00008392333984']
```

Trying this code:

```
new_setpoints_list = [75.00000762939453, 74.9999771118164, 75.0, 74.0, 75.99999237060547, 75.0, 74.0, 75.00008392333984]

devices_list = ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14/ZN-SP', 
           'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13/ZN-SP', 
           'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15/ZN-SP', 
           'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11/ZN-SP', 
           'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9/ZN-SP', 
           'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/7/ZN-SP', 
           'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21/ZN-SP', 
           'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/16/ZN-SP']

result = list(map("/".join, zip(devices_list,str(new_setpoints_list))))
```

`printing(result)` is something unwanted shown below any tips greatly appreciated.

```
['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14/ZN-SP/[',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13/ZN-SP/7',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15/ZN-SP/5',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11/ZN-SP/.',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9/ZN-SP/0',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/7/ZN-SP/0',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21/ZN-SP/0',
 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/16/ZN-SP/0']
```

Comment: This isn't list concatenation.

Comment: Don't convert the list as a whole to `str`, but the individual numbers, using `map(str, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = []
for count, i in enumerate(devices_list):
    url = i + "/" + str(new_setpoints_list[count])
    output.append(url)

for i in output:
    print(i)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`str(new_setpoints_list)` will just create the entire list  to a single string reprensetation, you need to convert each of the values in the list to string separately.

```py
>>> ['/'.join(v) for v in zip(devices_list, (str(x) for x in new_setpoints_list))]

['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14/ZN-SP/75.00000762939453', 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13/ZN-SP/74.9999771118164', 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15/ZN-SP/75.0', 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11/ZN-SP/74.0', 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9/ZN-SP/75.99999237060547', 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/7/ZN-SP/75.0', 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21/ZN-SP/74.0', 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/16/ZN-SP/75.00008392333984']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `str(new_setpoints_list)` inside of your `zip` function, you are casting the entire array as a string. This causes `zip` to treat the array object as one string. Instead, use a list comprehension to convert the numbers in the array into strings individually

```
result = list(map("/".join, zip(devices_list,[str(x) for x in new_setpoints_list])))
```